# Netsuite - XML to PDF, CSS question (string of text, but only show starting at character 13)

Tags: css, xml, netsuite

NetSuite, we have items.  I am trying to modify the XML they use to create our Estimate/Invoice PDFS.  I have items like this: Pre-Media - Operator Time.  We pre-append so that when our teams are creating estimates/invoices the many rates we have group with each other.  However we don't want the Pre-Media - part to show.  I'd just like it to read Operator Time.

I reviewed a few CSS markups overflow, ::after, but not sure where I should be looking.  I do like to do things on my own, but unfortunately I have a timeline :P. It has been a long while since I've played with CSS/HTML and coding in general so I'm re-wetting my feet.  Any thoughts?  TIA

```
<tr style="width:100%;">
<td align="left" colspan="15" line-height="150%" rowspan="1" style="width:50%;font-size:9pt;"><#if record.entity == 'Ford CA'>${item.item}<#else>${item.description}</#if></td>
<td align="right" colspan="7" line-height="150%" rowspan="1" style="width:30%;font-size:9pt;">${item.quantity} <span class="uom">${item.units}</span> x ${item.rate}</td><td colspan="26" style="width:20%;align:right;"> ${item.amount}</td>
</tr>
```

item.item is the field in question.  For non-Ford clients, I need to strip the first 12 characters from the item.item.  Currently I used the if statement above to cheat until I could figure it out.  My Account Service team went live with their new stuff and I had to quickly try to figure out how to get it to work.

I haven't worked on any coding (used to handcode) since 2007/2008, surprised not much has changed, but love the new stuff you can do.

Comment: Are you doing this in Freemarker/Advanced PDF?  Show us your code!

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: @Krypton Thank you!  Not sure why I didn't think of that :)

Answer (score 1):

There are several ways to achieve this, depending on the exact circumstances - the data and the version of Freemarker that's being used are a couple of considerations. I'm not sure what the current version that NetSuite uses is.

### Substring

*Note: This method is deprecated in later versions of Freemarker.*

This can be used to remove a known number of characters from the beginning of a string.  If the item codes *always* start with "Pre-Media - ", you can remove those 12 characters using:

`${item.item?substring(12)}`

### Slicing Expressions

*These are preferred over the `substring()` method from version 2.3.21*

Again, if the characters to be removed are always the same length (or alternatively you could wrap it in a conditional expression using `<#if><#else></#if>`.  I won't cover the details of that here.

`${item.item[12..]}`

### Replace

To only remove a specific substring *if it exists*, you can use the replace method.  This should work in any version.

`${item.item?replace("Pre-Media - ", "")}`

### Remove_beginning

*Available from version 2.3.21*

Best if some items start with a specified string and some don't, provided your Freemarker version is 2.3.21 or better.

`${item.item?remove_beginning("Pre-Media - ")}`

### Keep_after

*Available since 2.3.21*

If all the items have the pattern of {{prefix}} - {{item}}, you can use `keep_after()` to remove everything before the " - ".  (Also removes the " - ".)

`${item.item?keep_after(" - ")}`

This is not an exhaustive list of the ways to accomplish this, but it should get you pointed in the right direction.